# In Visual Studio 2015 asp.net mvc 6 project resourse files don't generate public class wiht public properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 generates `Resources.Designer.cs` file for the `Resources.rexs` files when you build the project. It generates an Internal class `Resources` with Internal Properties. How can I make Visual Studio generate a public class with public properties? For the `Resgen.exe` you can give a parameter `/publicClass`. Is there a place in Visual Studio 2015 with ASP.NET MVC 6 project to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but when you add / open a resx file, there is the `Access Modifier` drop down at the top of the window that gives you 3 options (Internal, Public & No Code Generation).

You can set that to `Public` and it will make all of the resources within the file public.

[image: Resources access modifier dropdown screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately the Access Modifier is disabled. If I open the Resource View (Ctrl+Shift+E) and look the Resources object's properties (Right Click) I can change the Access -field to vsCMAccessPublic. This makes the class public but not the properties?

Comment: Were you debugging when you tried it?  That's the only reason I can think it would be disabled.  Are you using some sort of 3rd party resource file type or plugin that might be impacting this?

Comment: I am not debugging and not using 3rd party resource file type (resources.rexs). Maybe the environment is not stable.